# E-mails got stuck in the delivery queue, wamp + hMailServer

Tags: php, email

I've created the `127.0.0.1` domain for my **hMailServer** and added `test@127.0.0.1` account with `123` password for it.
Under Settings -> Protocols -> SMTP -> Delivery of e-mail I have put `localhost` under "Local host name".

I use **wamp** server and **phpmailer** script to send e-mails. The script seems to works and says that the e-mail has been sent.
The problem is, I don't get e-mails on the given addresses and they got stuck in the delivery queue (hMailServer -> Status -> Delivery queue):
[image]

The script I use to send e-mails looks like this (I only changed the authorization data to match the local mail server and commented out `SMTPSecure`):

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost;smtp.localhost';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'test@127.0.0.1';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '123';                           // SMTP password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('contact@feydreamers.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('another-email@wp.pl');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if($mail->send()) { ...}
```

And the log of phpmailer looks good to me:

```
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 localhost ESMTP
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO test.localhost.com
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-localhost
250-SIZE 20480000
250-AUTH LOGIN
250 HELP
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: dGVzdEAxMjcuMC4wLjE=
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MTIz
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 authenticated.
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<from@example.com>
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<contact@feydreamers.com>
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<another-email@wp.pl>
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<cc@example.com>
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<bcc@example.com>
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 OK, send.
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sat, 6 May 2017 13:07:22 +0000
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Joe User <contact@feydreamers.com>, bor-der@wp.pl
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Mailer <from@example.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Cc: cc@example.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: Information <info@example.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Here is the subject
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <428148ffef5cd4a001fb4d8e93b6a4dc@borg.localhost.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.23 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_428148ffef5cd4a001fb4d8e93b6a4dc"
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_428148ffef5cd4a001fb4d8e93b6a4dc
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_428148ffef5cd4a001fb4d8e93b6a4dc
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_428148ffef5cd4a001fb4d8e93b6a4dc--
1: CLIENT -> SERVER:
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Queued (0.000 seconds)
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2: SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 goodbye
3: Connection: closed
```

Comment: When PHPMailer "sends" an email, it simply passes the email over to the mail server. If the mail server receives it correctly, you will get success and PHPMailer is done.
What actually happens after that (stuck in a queue, fails to send, bounces or successfully sends) is all up to the mail server so you're issue isn't with PHP or PHPMailer, it's with hMailserver (which is off topic for SO since it isn't really a programming question).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So I may feel 100% positive that the PHP part is all right and it's related to mail server and not my code? I mean, I just have to switch to another (working) mail server/host or find out why Mail server (and not script nor PHPMailer or PHP server) is not working for me on localhost?

Comment: Since you get a success from PHPMailer and you actually do see the emails in hMailserver (which means that PHP did successfully pass the mail over the mail server), I would say yes. (even though I'm trying to avoid saying 100% on anything. especially computer related. Weird things happen!).